# aws cloud9 lambda import failed

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I have a working production environment with several Lambda deployed from my PC using AWS SAM.

I want to transition my lambda to Cloud9 and debug from there but...

Some of the functions import well and I can run the debugger while others don't even show up after importing. This leads me to believe there might be a config issue that Cloud9 doesn't like.

I'll take a fairly simple lambda called uploaddirect and this is what it looks like:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion : '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: add docs directly from s3

Parameters:

  Environment:
    Type: String
    Default: staging
  DocumentMetadataBucketName:
    Type: String
  DocumentSourceBucketName:
    Type: String
  DocumentMetadataBucketArn:
    Type: String
  DocumentSourceBucketArn:
    Type: String

Resources:
  UploaddirectFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !Sub leopro-uploaddirect-function-${Environment}
      Handler: uploaddirect.handler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Timeout: 300
      Role: !GetAtt UploaddirectExecutionRole.Arn
      Environment:
        Variables:
          DOCUMENT_METADATA_BUCKET: !Ref DocumentMetadataBucketName
          DOCUMENT_SOURCE_BUCKET: !Ref DocumentSourceBucketName
      CodeUri: .

  UploaddirectExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Sub leopro-uploaddirect-exec-role-${Environment}
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
      Policies:
        -
          PolicyName: !Sub leopro-uploaddirect-access-s3-${Environment}
          PolicyDocument:
            Version: "2012-10-17"
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "s3:GetObject"
                  - "s3:PutObject"
                Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::*/*'
            Statement:
              -
                Effect: "Allow"
                Action:
                  - "s3:*"
                Resource: '*'
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: "2012-10-17"
        Statement:
          -
            Effect: "Allow"
            Principal:
              Service:
                - "lambda.amazonaws.com"
            Action:
              - "sts:AssumeRole"

  UploaddirectBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      BucketName: !Sub leopro-uploaddirect-dropbox-bucket-${Environment}
      NotificationConfiguration:
        LambdaConfigurations:
          -
            Event: 's3:ObjectCreated:*'
            Function: !GetAtt UploaddirectFunction.Arn

  UploaddirectBucketPolicy:
      Type: AWS::S3::BucketPolicy
      Properties:
        Bucket: !Ref UploaddirectBucket
        PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
            -
              Action:
                - "s3:GetObject"
              Effect: "Allow"
              Resource: !Sub "arn:aws:s3:::leopro-uploaddirect-dropbox-bucket-${Environment}/*"
              Principal: "*"

  InvokeFromS3Permission:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt UploaddirectFunction.Arn
      Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
      Principal: "s3.amazonaws.com"
      SourceArn: !Join [ "", [ "arn:aws:s3:::", !Sub "leopro-uploaddirect-dropbox-bucket-${Environment}" ] ]
```

I tried plenty of things including changing the function name, redeploying, clearing my cache, restarting cloud9, deleting folders ...

Any ideas?

Comment: Still no luck !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The naming conventions of functions can be a problem when importing, specially if there are conditional parameters.

The way I solved it was to create another project with exactly same settings and code (diff compare) and changed the names of the stack, the app, the functions and the policies.

Comment: I noticed one other thing, Some variations of the lambda execution role will stop de function from displaying under the Local Functions tree